# Need assistance in modifying the python script to return wind direction in degrees

Tags: python

I am new to scripting and have only worked on arcpy modules specifically. I am currently using the scripts to get the wind details from "http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations". I need to integrate the wind direction in the web application and need assistance in modify the script to return only wind direction in degrees, Here is the link that I have downloaded the scripts from "http://pypi.python.org/pypi/metar/"
I have tried making the changes to Metar.py by adding a function to return direction only

```
 def windDirection(self):
      """
      Return a textual description of the wind conditions.

      Units may be specified as "MPS", "KT", "KMH", or "MPH".
      """
      if self.wind_speed == None:
          return "missing"
      elif self.wind_speed.value() == 0.0:
          text = "calm"
      else:
          wind_speed = self.wind_speed.string(units)
          text = "%s"(self.wind_dir.directVal)
      return text
```

Also added a function to Datatypes.py"

```
def directVal( self ):
    if not self._compass:
      degrees = 22.5 * round(self._degrees/22.5)
      if degrees == 360.0:
        self._directVal = "N"
      else:
        for name, d in direction.compass_dirs.iteritems():
          if d == degrees:
            self._directVal = name
            break
    return self._directVal
```

I am not sure how to get this value returned as a separate text strong other than report. Please assist.

Comment: Does making this change help? text = "%s" % (self.wind_dir.directVal, )

Comment: what purpose does this line have? `wind_speed = self.wind_speed.string(units)`

Comment: no it doesn't. I have copied the wind function to new function directVal(). I can skip the above line as I do not specify the units in the return value.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to METAR data (if you are in the US) is to connect to the station's NOAA observation XML data. While that is a bit lengthy to wade through, you can get a simple answer by using my PARFAIT API. To get back the current wind speed at LAX airport you'd use the Current Weather API: http://parfait.snarkybox.com/current.php?icao=klax&datum=current_observation,wind_mph

Full instructions are available on the API website: parfait dot snarkybox dot com.